# ownCloud stay logged in with files_external

Tags: authentication, owncloud

I'm using ownCloud via the Docker image `owncloud/server:10.5` and miss a *Stay logged in* checkbox. The [documentation](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.5/user_manual/webinterface.html) says that apps like `files_external` will disable this checkbox. There are some users on my server who have active external storages which I don't want to remove by disabling `files_external`. Is there a way to use ownCloud with external storage support and permanent sessions?

For more security I have enabled *Oauth2* and *2-Factor Authentication* but disabling these apps does not bring the *Stay logged in* checkbox back.